# game matching Phil Rizzuto call in Meat Loaf song?

Tags: baseball, media

Has there ever been an actual baseball game which exactly matched the [call](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/m/meat+loaf/paradise+by+the+dashboard+light_20091297.html) (scroll down to *Radio Broadcast*) made by Phil Rizzuto in the *Meat Loaf* song *Paradise by the Dashboard Light*?

Namely: 2 outs, bases empty, bottom of the 9th -- a sliding double, stolen 3rd base, and a bunt up the 3rd base line for a suicide squeeze.  Doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: no, that play doesn't come from a specific game

The story behind the play can be found in [this article](http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/page2/story?page=pearlman/070816), but below is the important bit:

> From all those days and nights in front of the television, Meat Loaf -- along with legendary song writer Jim Steinman -- pieced together what is, without question, the most famous baseball play-by-play call in the history of sexually themed rock 'n' roll songs...
>
> Rizzuto arrived at Manhattan's The Hit Factory one day in 1976, met with Meat Loaf and Steinman and read over his lines. He initially expected to sing something...then asked why every play was so close. When he finally recorded, Rizzuto's delivery was flat and wooden. "Just do it like it's a game," Meat Loaf advised.

Undaunted, I tried using Baseball-Reference.com's Play Index and Game Index, searching for a 1-0 walk-off win by the home team in 9 innings with at least 1 double, at least 1 stolen base, and without a home run. While I couldn't figure out how to search exclusively for a batter hitting a double to center field with two outs in the bottom of the 9th, advancing to 3rd on a stolen base, and then scoring on a suicide squeeze, I wanted to at least get a manageable list of games to individually check. From 1914-1977 (the year Meat Loaf's *Bat Out of Hell* was released), there apparently are nine games that fit those criteria, but you need to be a subscriber to the site to get said list.

Comment: To make it even more difficult, it doesn't have to be a win... in the song, Rizzuto doesn't get a chance to call the result of the play at the plate

Comment: *gasp* You're right. I guess I'm an optimist after all. (:

Comment: http://retrosheet.org has freely available digital play-by-play data for nearly all major league games since 1920, which someone with sufficient interest could process.